# Creating new table with multiple values in a column

Tags: oracle, insert

I have created a table with only one column

```
Create Table RLID_MARK
(
RLID Int )
```

I want to Add multiple values in Column RLID using

```
insert into RLID_MARK (RLID)
values( '43230335' ,    '20936450' ,    '39685560' ,    '50833640' ,    '78406124' ,)
```

but its showing

```
Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Kindly help me to get exact method.
thnk you in advance

Comment: The question needs clarifying. Do you want a single row with a multi-valued column (= column RLID should be a list of values) ?  Or should each value go in a different row ? And if so you have been given several answers.

Comment: can't really support putting multiple values in a single field - this violates almost everything normalization tries to optimize

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

from 9i onward oracle knows insert all ..

use the following syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO RLID_MARK (RLID) VALUES (43230335)
   INTO RLID_MARK (RLID) VALUES (20936450)
   INTO RLID_MARK (RLID) VALUES (39685560)
   INTO RLID_MARK (RLID) VALUES (50833640)
   INTO RLID_MARK (RLID) VALUES (78406124)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

this only carries the overhead of repeating the column names per insert line ..if that is still too much writing - you can use PLSQL

```
declare
   procedure ins
      (v_RLID INTEGER)
   is
   begin
      insert into RLID_MARK 
      (RLID)
      values
      (v_RLID);
   end;
begin
   ins (43230335);
   ins (20936450);
   ins (39685560);
   ins (50833640);
   ins (78406124);
end;
/
```